# Strip tags and keep content with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I thought this question would have been answered 1000 times, but apparently not (or I'm not looking right!). I want to clean up some overloaded HTML content with BeautifulSoup and remove unwanted tags. In some cases (e.g. `<span>` or `<div>`), I want to preserve the content of the tag instead of destroying it entirely with `decompose`.

With LXML, this can be achieved with `strip_tag`. How do I do that with BS4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [unwrap](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) method. It preserves content.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I have to say I'm always confused with their terminology!